# CDT compare broken?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Help. I have been relying on the compare editor for code review, and it mostly works quite well.
But for some reason, on some files, it is giving me inconsistent results and telling me that some code is different when it is not. It can't seem to deal with commented out code in this file.
It tells me that later functions are different and tries to match lines in those functions.
I have also found cases where it simply thinks the code is different but it is not.
It then decides that there must be changes in hundreds of lines below this.
I am able to work around by remove the code with #if 0, #endif, but it is not pretty.

Has anyone else seen this and do you know of any way to fix it?

I am trying to get a clean diff do I can see just the actual changes between the files.
It is driving me to drink - and it is still early in the day!

Comment: +1 "It is driving me to drink - and it is still early in the day!"

Comment: Ok, I have a workaround. Beyond Compare does not have this problem. So for now I am using Tortoise CVS together with the (trial version) of Beyond compare to do my diff. Not great - but it works for now.